# Java. Ошибка нехватает ";" после throw java.io.IOException

Tags: java

[image: Выдает ошибку Error:(3, 34) java: ';' expected]

когда вставляю ; пишет ошибку 
Error:(3, 19) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class io
  location: package java

Не понимаю как исправить, только учусь Java, плз направьте на правильный путь

Код:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        throw java.io.IOException {
            char ch;

            System.out.println("Push");

            ch = (char) System.out.read();
            System.out.println("Now you press " + ch + " button");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В сигнатуре метода должно быть throw**s**, а не throw.

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя просто ошибки в синтаксисе: лишние скобки "{}", затем вместо `throws` у тебя `throw`, а также для чтения из консоли используют `System.in.read()`, а у тебя `System.out.read()`. Правильно будет так:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
        throws java.io.IOException {
            char ch;
            System.out.println("Push");
            ch = (char) System.in.read();
            System.out.println("Now you press " + ch + " button");        
    }
}
```

В данной программе выполняется чтение из консоли через метод `System.in.read()`, который может выбросить исключение и это исключение необходимо как-то обработать.
Исключение можно возбудить (еще говорят "бросить", что является дословным переводом throw) используя оператор (кто бы мог подумать))) `throw`. Делается это путем создания объекта типа `Thowable`, либо его подкласса. Сигнатура стандартная для создания объекта в Java:

```
throw new java.io.IOException("Demo");// с описанием исключения
```

как вариант:

```
throw new java.io.IOException(); // без описания исключения
```

Для твоего примера есть два варианта.

Первый:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            char ch;
            System.out.println("Push");
            ch = (char)System.in.read();
            System.out.println("Now you press " + ch + " button");
        }catch(java.io.IOException e){
            System.out.println("We have an Error in our programm");
        }        
    }
}
```

Здесь выполняется перехват и обработка прямо в данном коде возможного возникновения исключения через оператор `catch`. Т.е. при нештатной ситуации (в д.случае) на консоль будет выведена надпись "We have an Error in our programm".

Второй (как у тебя в коде):

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException{
        char ch;
        System.out.println("Push");
        ch = (char)System.in.read();
        System.out.println("Now you press " + ch + " button");              
    }
}
```

здесь мы сами не перехватываем возможное исключение, а "пробрасываем" исключение выше, через добавление `throws java.io.IOException` в основную сигнатуру метода, в д.сл. Main, как указывал в комментарии Sergey Gornostaev.
Советую внимательно почитать про исключения в Java.